# Find object's property inside array using other property

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to "link" the Genre property in each of these objects inside this array to the title property that outputs to the user inside `value`.

```
var movies= [{
    "Title": "Platoon",
    "Genre": "War"
}, {
    "Title": "Pulp Fiction",
    "Genre": "Crime"
}];

var name = value;
//console.log(name) outputs as title the user clicked on just fine

var genre = ...["Genre"]; //no idea how to go about this
//this should say genre = ["Genre"] in object where ["Title"] is same as value
```

Tried the IndexOf method to at least retrieve the element by searching for "Genre", but it outputs `-1`.

Comment: why not just iterate over the array and search for the title ?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: I've read this five times, and I still don't get it? Do you want two arrays?

Comment: Can you include portion of `javascript` where `value` is set at user `click` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function findGenre(title) {
    function search(a, i) {
        if (a.Title === title) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
  
    var index;
    if (movies.some(search)) {
        return movies[index].Genre;
    }
}

var movies= [{ Title: "Platoon", Genre: "War" }, { Title: "Pulp Fiction", Genre: "Crime" }];

console.log(findGenre('Platoon'));
```

Comment: This answer works for me but one question: If "Title" in the object had spaces, I mean if the property was "Movie Title" instead of "Title", how would you apply that change to `(a.Title === title)` as well?

Comment: you could use the bracket notation: `a.['Movie Title'] === title`. please have a look to [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop should do it.

```
var genre;
for(var i=0; i< movies.length; i++) {
  if (movies[i].Title === name) {
    genre = movies[i].Genre;
    break; // stop the loop assuming title is unique
  }
}
```

```js
var movies= [{
    "Title": "Platoon",
    "Genre": "War"
}, {
    "Title": "Pulp Fiction",
    "Genre": "Crime"
}];

var name = 'Pulp Fiction';

var genre;
for(var i=0; i< movies.length; i++) {
  if (movies[i].Title === name) {
    genre = movies[i].Genre;
    break;
  }
}

alert(genre);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
  var found = movies.filter(function(m) { 
     return m.Title === value 
  });

  if (found.length > 0) { 
    console.log(found[0].Genre); // or handle some way different if more than one match found 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..of` loop, object destructuring to get values by checking if `.innerHTML` of clicked element is equal to value of `Title` property of object

```js
var movies= [{
    "Title": "Platoon",
    "Genre": "War"
}, {
    "Title": "Pulp Fiction",
    "Genre": "Crime"
}];

var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
var [value, genre] = [null, null];
for (let el of divs) {
  el.onclick = (e) => {
    for (let props of movies) {
      let {Title, Genre} = props;
      if (Title === e.target.innerHTML) {   
        [value, genre] = [Title, Genre];
        console.log(`value:${value}, genre:${genre}`);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Platoon</div>
<div>Pulp Fiction</div>
```